# Как сделать диалоговое окно?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Предположим есть окно в котором в виде таблице отображается некий список, для каждой записи есть некий набор действий, для примера пусть будут *"Edit"/"Detail"/"Delete"*.

При выборе пользователем пункта *"Delete"* необходимо показать окно с неким предупреждающим текстом, и двумя возможными действиями: *"Ok"/"Cancel"*.

Как бы я это сделал в [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) приложении:

```
var dialogBox = new DialogBox.ShowModal();
if(dialogBox.DialogResult == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    //здесь код который должен быть сделан в случае подтверждения действия
}
//здесь то что надо сделать в случае отмены
```

В рамках [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm), необходимо сделать *View*, *ModelView*, т.е. у нас должно быть что то типа `Main`, `MainViewModel`, `Dialog`, `DialogViewModel`;

в `Main` - будут кнопки которые будут прибиндины к командам из ViewModel. т.е. например так могла бы выглядеть команда для *"Delete"*:

```
private void Delete()
{
    var dialog = new Dialog(new DialogViewModel())
    dialog.Show();
    //здесь как то надо сделать проверку на то что случилось в диалоге
}
```

Как вариант можно сделать публичное свойство в DialogViewModel с типом `boolean` и устанавливать его в диалоге, по нажатии на любую из кнопок (Ok/Canсel) менять его значение, в главной форме смотреть значение этого свойства. Вот только меня терзают сомнения в правильности такого подхода.

Как сделать *Диалоговое окно* в [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) с использованием [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm)?

***P.S.: код писал здесь, могут быть ошибки***

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему

Comment: @KromStern попытался написать более развернуто

Comment: Теперь гораздо лучше. Поставил плюсик за развернутость

Comment: Вопрос то в чем? Если у вас простой диалог уточнение - то это может быть на совести вьюшки\вьюмодели целиком. Пилить каждый раз на каждый чих вьюшки и вьюмодели к ним тоже не надо. С другой стороны, если таких диалогов в целом набирается хотя бы штук 5, то наверно стоит вынести куда то в отдельный класс возможность просто во вьюмодели сказать что нужен запрос подтверждения с таким то текстом\иконкой\кнопками. И тут уж ессна надо делать нормальную модель диалога и вьюшку диалога.

Comment: @Monk вопрос в реализации, после поисков примера, не нашел ничего однозначного, где то идет отсылка на сторонние компоненты, где то сам код вызывает легкий трепет, не ужели все так плохо. почему в winforms это было намного проще, если Вам несложно может Вы напишите ответ с примером кода

Comment: @Bald Однозначного решения и нет, визуально такие вещи закрываются по желанию заказчика. Я вот тупо пишу `var dialog = Dialogs.CreateTask(Title, Message, IconType.Warning)` и `var result = dialog.ShowModal() == Buttons.Ok` во вьюмодели и все вполне рабочее и приятное для использования.

Comment: @Monk что бы так тупо написать Вы сначала *реализовали* свой класс `Dialogs` (Model), представление (View), логику (ViewModel), теперь это конечно легко и тупо. а я пока не реализовал это для себя и даже не знаю как сделать, наверно придется останавливаться на публичном свойстве в диалоге и проверять его из главного окна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь есть два варианта действий:

1. Более простой способ, но более неудобный в случае, если вы    используете TDD: Вам нет необходимости создавать ViewModel и View    отдельно для диалогового окна: достаточно перед удалением проверять  ответ пользователя в диалоговом окне следующим образом:

   ```
       if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to delete item?", "Delete confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
       {
           modelInstance.Delete(); //execute delete
       }
   ```
2. Более трудоёмкий способ, но с соблюдением всех канонов MVVM: создаёте ViewModel для вашего диалогового окна. Во ViewModel создаёте событие, например:

   ```
   public event EventHandler ConfirmEvent;
   ```

Событие нужно декорировать специальным аттрибутом, который позволит транслировать его в другие ViewModel-классы, не нарушая при этом принцип high-cohesion loose-coupling. Для этого используются мессенджеры. Можете попробовать Appcelerate.EventBroker. В своих проектах я использую именно его.

Далее - создаёте команду, которая ссылается на метод, вызывающий вышеупомянутое событие. Привязываете команду к кнопке в вашем диалоговом окне.

```
    private ICommand confirmCommand;

    public ICommand ConfirmCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(confirmCommand==null)
            {
                confirmCommand = new Command(p => FireConfirmEvent(), p => ConfirmEventPredicate());
            }
            return confirmCommand;
        }
    }
```

В самом окне при помощи метода, декорированного аттрибутом из того же мессенджера обрабатываете это событие. Метод будет содержать код, выполняющий удаление.

View в этом случае создавайте, как пару Window.xaml + Window.cs, у которого есть метод ShowDialog(), что автоматически заблокирует вызывающее окно на время открытия диалогового.

PS: первый способ не совсем правильный, потому что будет сложно тестировать результат, выбранный пользователем в MessageBox.

**Добавлено**
Если захотите использовать это окно в разных местах вашего приложения, создайте базовый абстрактный класс, а в унаследованных VM-классах перегрузите нужные вам свойства. Например, в некоторых случаях вам может понадобиться «дернуть» несколько событий, чтобы на подтверждение среагировало несколько  ViewModel. Тут всё зависит от сложности проекта.

Answer (score -1):

Может быть так:

Делаешь окошко с двумя кнопками и со статическим методом Create:

```
public partial class XDialogOkCancel : Window
{
    public static Boolean CreateXDialogOkCancel()
    {
        var wnd = new XDialogOkCancel();
        if (wnd.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }    

    private XDialogOkCancel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOk_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void buttonCancel_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false; //Или поставь IsCansel=true в XAML
    }
}
```

И вызываешь его из своего метода:

```
private void Delete()
{
    if( XDialogOkCancel.CreateXDialogOkCancel())
    {
        //делаю
    }
    else
    {
        //Не делаю
    }
}
```